# Latency issue in Python plus Django application

Tags: python, django

I have developed an application in Python 2.7.13 with Django 1.9.7 MYSQL . The application works fine. We deployed the same application in another server of higher hardware configuration but with Python version 2.7.5 with Django 1.9.7 & same version of MySQL. But this new deployment sometimes has severe latency issues but runs fine most of the time. I have compared the services running on the new server are same at the time of latency with when it runs fine. Log file does not show any unusual thing. Can someone provide some clue what we should look for?

Comment: probably you should be more specific about: "latency issues but runs fine most of the time"

Comment: Install django-debug-toolbar, that way you can see what queries are taking up the most time and work out if something needs indexed / optimized. Take it from there.